# How to update the periphera.name of the bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, texas-instruments

I'm creating a Bluetooth LE application to track texas instrument bluetooth devices.

- In the device log of the iPhone, the peripheral name of the bluetooth device is "Cannon Tag" which is what I want it to be called.
- In the device log of the iPad, the peripheral name of the bluetooth device is "TI BLE Keyfob".

I want it to read the Cannon Tag for the iPad. How do I make this change?

Answer (score 1):

The device name characteristic is not writable by default. You need to recompile the project with the desired name. In the KeyFob project you need to change this line in the `keyfobdemo.c` file.

```
static uint8 attDeviceName[GAP_DEVICE_NAME_LEN] = "TI BLE Keyfob";
```

Then recompile and upload it to the device. This is not a trivial task, so if you encounter issues, I suggest you ask on the TI forums and read tutorials.